# Rendering with NN Interpolation

Tags: rendering, texturing

I have a high resolution texture with only seven colors that I apply to a makehuman model and I want in my rendered result also just those seven colors (plus a black background).

So far I have tried to to deactivate MIP Map and Interpolation, and different filters with small filter sizes in the Image Sampling panel. However, the result is as depicted in the following image:

[image]

Further, I tried to deactivate the Anti-Aliasing in the Render options, but still I do not get the desired result:

[image]

You see that the color fades, especially on color borders. The rendered image is rather small (160x120), but also if I increase the dimension, the problem remains.

Comment: Are you using BI or cycles?

Comment: In the current setup: BI.

Answer (score 4):

Deactivating *AA* and *MipMap* + *Interpolation* is the right thing to do. The filters are used with interpolation. The bigger the filter size the smoother the result becomes. But since you don't want any smoothness you should deactivate interpolation. That way you can forget about filters.

Nevertheless Blender seems to sample textures internally with some interpolation.

As a workaround you could use an image manipulation program like GIMP or Photoshop and reduce the colors there. In GIMP you can do it like this: Image > Mode > Indexed.

To automate this task for multiple images you can use BIMP. It is GIMP plugin which is probably already installed. You can find it in File > Batch Image Manipulation...
You can use the filter called "gimp-image-convert-indexed"

Comment: Is there no way to deactivate this sampling? The GIMP solution is a bit cumbersome, especially if have a lot of images that I have to postprocess in this way.

Comment: Maybe add a note about the *Filter Size* option as well?

Comment: Do you mean the _Filter Size_ option in the _Image Sampling_ panel? There I have tried the smallest value, the largest value and this in combination with every filter - no luck. Also if I check the _Minimum Filter Size_ the result is still not like I want it.

Comment: I'm thinking a shadeless material would also help.

Comment: I updated my answer for multiple image batch processing.

Answer (score 2):

You could try and make a [node setup which quantizes the colors](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Composite_Nodes/Types/Convertor#Quantize.2FRestrict_Color_Selection) automatically, e.g:

[image]

## Cycles

You could do this in cycles by using a mix shader to mix diffuse shaders based on your textures:

1. Set up a material that uses black and white textures as to define which color of diffuse should be used where:

   [image]
2. Set the number of samples to `1` in *Render settings > Sampling*:

   [image]
3. Enable the *Diffuse color pass* in *Render layers > Passes*:

   [image]
4. Use the *Diffuse color pass* as the output:

   [image]

As you can see, only the colors specified in the diffuse nodes are used.

Comment: I tried your approach and it does definitely restrict the colors in the output picture. Unfortunately I am somehow restricted in the colors. Further, and more problematic, at the borders I still get some other colors.

Comment: @Masala You could try using an external batch image processor such as [*Image magick*](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#posterize) to do this.

Comment: My current solution is to have n textures, render n times and then make a batch postprocessing with an external programm. The problem with this solution is, that the rendering process takes now of course n times longer. Is there a way to render an image with different textures in the compositor?

Comment: @Masala I'm not sure what you mean.. Isn't that square one?

Comment: Currently, I have a small Python script and one texture for one color. In the script I apply the _i_-th texture of _n_ and then render the model in a loop (therefore, _n_ renders). The question is, if it is possible to render the model just once, but apply different textures in the compositor, and have _n_ different file output nodes.

Comment: @Masala AFAIK, no.

Comment: @Masala I thought of a way to do this in cycles, not sure if that will help. It is possible to make a "posterize" node setup in the compositor, but I haven't been successful yet.